# Sync offline documents created by another user

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore

It is not clear to me how firebase (firestore) handles the following scenario (React Native app)

- A user signed in
- The device went offline
- The user created and added a new document (obviously it would be saved offline)
- The user signed out
- The device went back online
- A **new** user signed in

Question: will the pending added offline document be pushed to the firestore?

My experiment showed that the offline document sync does not happen until the same user signs in again. However I could not find any official document else where for this behaviour.

Comment: I think you should expect the behavior that you're seeing, because security rules will ultimately determine who is actually allowed to make changes.  Security rules that depend on the current user will require that the correct user actually be signed in with Firebase Auth at the time the SDK performs the write.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any document or code that can confirm that behaviour?

Comment: You can contact Firebase support directly with questions that you feel are not adequately addressed in the documentation.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support